# GStreamer; Unable to pause - ""; Error: "No URI set" - MediaPlayer QML Type

Tags: linux, qt, qml, media-player, qt5

Tried the following from http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#details

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Window
{
    visible: true
    height: 1000
    width: 1000


    MediaPlayer {
        id: mediaplayer
        source: "/home/****/template/v1.avi"
    }

    VideoOutput {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: mediaplayer
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: playArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onPressed: mediaplayer.play();
    }
}
```

on

`Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l`

with

`GStreamer Core Library version 0.10.36`

This gives the error shown in title on click.
I have confirmed that the file exists.

What else can be done now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set the `url` in Linux is:

`file:///home/***/template/v1.avi`

So, `source: "/home/****/template/v1.avi"` should be replaced by:

`source: "file:///home/***/template/v1.avi"`